# Почему js скрипт не работает в отдельном файле, который содержит js скрипты и подключен к основному файла на *.php?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь вывести из тэга `<span id="st">1</span>` значение 1 все получается, как только этот код размещаю не в самом файле *.php а в отдельном файле для скриптов *.js то код не работает. Подскажите как сделать чтобы этот код запускался из другого файла ?

```
<html>


     <body>
        <span id="st">1</span>
<script src="/project/unix.js" defer async> 

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>

<script>
var page = document.getElementById('st');
var fff =page.firstChild.nodeValue;
alert(fff);
</script>
```

Comment: `<script src="путь_к_вашему.js/>`

Comment: `<script src="/project/unix.js" defer async> 
   
   </script` у меня в проекте так написано, остальные скрипты работают идеально. Что с этим кодом я не знаю, не работает и все(

Comment: `async` уберите :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно скрипт подгружается раньше чем DOM.

```
function ready() {
......
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

А вообще какую ошибку пишет в консоли?